# Kafka client 0.10.0.0 Java not getting duplicate record more than 2499

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka client 0.10.0.0 and I am sending a file having 2800 records in it using

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_consumer_topic < 2800Rec.txt
```

But my client only reads 2499 records in poll.

One more thing when I send one non duplicate record then my consumer poll 2500 record.
So is there anything in Kafka which only stores 2499 duplicate records in kafka.

Comment: May be the log compaction feature is coming into play? - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compactionbasics

Comment: Thanks @BijuKunjummen I didn't read about this

Comment: You have to ensure all the events have been successfully delivered to Kafka. Use 'bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list broker1:9092 --topic test --time -1' to check first.

Comment: How big is your 2800Rec.txt input file? You may be trying to publish a message that is larger than the configured maximum message size.

Comment: @HansJespersen first time all the record saved on kafka but 2nd time with the same file some records were not saved.                                for example :                                                                                              <ol> I sent 3000 records all are saved successfully on the partition. My consumer read all the 3000 records (0-2099 offset)    </ol>                         <ol>sent same records again this time my consumer just read 2499 only</ol>